# How to deply/mount a linux distro from .tar file

Tags: mount

I am still new to linux work so please bear with me... 
I have an linux distribution on .tar file and I want to mound it to an sd card so I can run it on an imx6 board. I was able to create a directory and tar/untar the file into my development computer which is running ubuntu 12 and I can see that everything seems normal inside this directory (bin, bindary, dev, boot, ...). Now I want to move this directory into the sd card. Is there a deployment tool to copy the contents of this file into the sd card and possibly do the partitioning if needed? I hope this was clear enough.

Thanks.

Comment: If, as you describe it, there were a bunch of dirs inside the tar file, then that it not an image. Usually, there would be just one .img file, and you'd write it to an sdcard using the `dd` command. Copying a bunch of dirs would not accomplish much. In short, look for an image (.img), for example http://www.timesys.com/embedded-linux/resources/dev-center/imx6#demos.

Comment: @mikewhatever the image did not come as .img rather it was a .tar file - I assume this is possible

Comment: Well, you can call something an image, which is not an image. It is possible, but doesn't make it an image.

Comment: @mikewhatever what do you call it then?

Comment: ...and bunch of archived dirs and files. If you read `man tar`, it says "tar — The GNU version of the tar archiving utility". Where did you get that it from?

Answer (score 1):

1. Determine what the SD card device name is.  This can be done by doing `ls -1 /dev > before`, pluging in the SD card, then running `ls -1 /dev > after; diff before after`. This should output something like, `usb1`.[via stackoverflow](https://superuser.com/questions/352598/how-to-find-the-dev-name-of-my-usb-device%20stackoverflow).
2. `mount` the device to the filesystem, ala `mount -t vfat -o rw,umask=000 /dev/usb1 /mnt/sdcard`[via ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1985599%20ubuntuforums).
3. Copy your files into `/mnt/sdcard`.